# Lollipop Firmware for Galaxy Core Prime SM G360H

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates, samsung, device-firmware

Alright, so... I know there is no Lollipop Update (either OTA or Manual Firmware download) for the Galaxy Core Prime SM G360H yet. But my question is: Can I use the SM G360F's 5.0.2 Firmware on the SM G360H? I guess it should work but the 360H is Dual SIM and has no NFC. Will this be an issue? I will root the phone afterwards and I know for sure how to manually update it. I just want to know if the 360F's firmware will be fully compatible and usable on the 360H.

Comment: unfortunately, it's not. you cannot use firmware of 360F on 360H.

Comment: unfortunately (again), it doesn't possible! To do this, will be absolutely makes your phone hard bricked. Despite of phones have same name on the market, they have different cpu types and chipsets!

Answer (score 0):

No, these devices are not compatible; they use different chipsets.  The G360H uses a [Spreadtrum SC8830A](http://www.phonemore.com/phone/samsung-galaxy-core-prime-duos-sm-g360h/2003) (ARMv7) whereas the G360F uses a [Snapdragon 410 MSM8916](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=7245&c=samsung_sm-g360f_galaxy_core_prime_lte) (64-bit ARMv8).